# Class Attribute Overwritten in Renderless Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, renderless-component

I've built a renderless base icon Vue component that just outputs whatever is in its slot but with some additional attributes added to the slotted component. One of the attributes I set is `class="icon"` which allows me to have my styles for all icons in one place.

### Icon.vue

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  name: "u-icon",
  render(createElement) {
    const svg = this.$slots.default[0];
    const attrs = svg.data.attrs;

    attrs.xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    attrs.class = "icon";
    attrs["aria-hidden"] = "true";
    attrs.focusable = "false";
    attrs.role = "img";

    return this.$slots.default;
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.icon {
  // ...
}
</style>
```

### Close-Icon.vue

I can then more easily create many different icon components such as this close icon component.

```
<template>
  <u-icon>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
      <line x1="4" y1="4" x2="20" y2="20"></line>
      <line x1="4" y1="20" x2="20" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </u-icon>
</template>

<script>
import icon from "~/icon.vue";
export default {
  name: "close-icon",
  components: {
    "u-icon": icon,
  },
};
</script>
```

### Actual Outcome

The problem is when I use the `close-icon` component and set a `class` like so:

```
<close-icon class="foo"/>
```

The rendered output is not combining the two classes `"icon foo"`.

```
<svg class="foo" ...>
  ...
</svg>
```

### Expected Outcome

How can I ensure that the class is not overwritten but appended to so that the output is:

```
<svg class="icon foo" ...>
  ...
</svg>
```

If possible, any changes I make should be made to `Icon.vue` and I'd like to avoid making changes to `Close-Icon.vue` since there are a large number of other icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` and `style` bindings are not part of the [$attrs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) - [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0368ba4f37ef1ef28eb785261ab76a68f7fa03dd/types/vnode.d.ts#L41)

I'm not sure why your code even work without the `class` binding on `close-icon` **but** if you want to add/modify the classes of existing VNode (coming from default slot), you should use `svg.data.staticClass` instead of `svg.data.attrs.class`

Example below even handles the case in which static class is also placed directly on the `svg` element inside `close-icon` - renders `<svg class="foo bar icon" ...`

```js
Vue.component("u-icon", {  
  render(createElement) {
    const svg = this.$slots.default[0];
    const attrs = svg.data.attrs;
    
    attrs.xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    attrs["aria-hidden"] = "true";
    attrs.focusable = "false";
    attrs.role = "img";
    
    svg.data.staticClass = (svg.data.staticClass || "") + " icon";

    return this.$slots.default;
  },
});

Vue.component("close-icon", {
  template:`
  <u-icon>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" class="bar">
      <line x1="4" y1="4" x2="20" y2="20"></line>
      <line x1="4" y1="20" x2="20" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </u-icon>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <close-icon class="foo"></close-icon>
</div>
```